# What's wrong with my Python?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I've put together this script to help me perform a search across specific files. It does something similar to grep, but I needed something a little more specific than what grep offers, so I'm trying my hand at Python.

I've got one class which has three methods. The second method `listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile` (on line 30) fails. It's a small script, but since tabs matter in Python, I've put it into a [a gist, here](https://gist.github.com/MosheBerman/5766196). Can anyone tell my why my seemingly valid Python is invalid?

```
import os
import keyword
import sys


class Toodles:

    def walkAndList(directory):
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):

            # print path to all filenames.
            for filename in filenames:
                workingFilename = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                if(isSourceFile(filename)):
                    listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(filename)

            # Advanced usage:
            # editing the 'dirnames' list will stop os.walk() from recursing into there.
            if '.git' in dirnames:
                # don't go into any .git directories.
                dirnames.remove('.git')

            for dirs in dirnames:
                self.walkAndList(os.path.join(dirname, dirs)


    #   Find occurences of "todo" and "fixme" in a file
    #   If we find such an occurence, print the filename, 
    #   the line number, and the line itself.
    def listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(aFileName):
        input = open(aFileName)
        currentLine = 1
        for (line in input):
            line = line.lower()
            currentLine = currentLine + 1
            needle = "todo"
            if (needle in line):
                sys.stdout.write(aFileName + " (" + str(currentLine) + ")" + line)

    #Todo: add a comment
    def isSourceFile(self, name):
        fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(name)
        if (".m" in fileExtension or ".c" in fileExtension or ".h" in fileExtension):
            return True
        return False


if ( __name__ == "__main__") {
    a = Toodles()
    a.walkAndList('.')
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting `__main__` block.

Comment: Others have pointed out the problem. I would like to add: (1) is there some reason why you use `sys.stout.write` instead of just `print`? (2) What purpose is served by `class Toodles`? What is a Toodles? You don't need a class to group related functionality, your module already serves that purpose. If you can't explain what a Toodles is and why those functions are methods of a Toodles object, then best just to implement them as straight-up functions. (3) Someone said this already, but the brackets in `if (condition):` (and similarly in your `for` loops) are superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Like I said, I'm totally new to Python, so this is a learning experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
 self.walkAndList(os.path.join(dirname, dirs)
```

Note that there are two opening, but only one closing parens.

Next problem is that you are using curly braces further down:

```
if ( __name__ == "__main__") {
    a = Toodles()
    a.walkAndList('.')
}
```

This is Python, not C, Java or Javascript; remove the braces and use a colon:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Toodles()
    a.walkAndList('.')
```

Then you are using parenthesis in a `for` statement in a way that is not legal Python:

```
for (line in input):
```

Remove those parenthesis:

```
for line in input:
```

Next problem is that you don't define `self` for two of your methods:

```
def walkAndList(directory):
```

and

```
def listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(aFileName):
```

Add `self` as a first parameter:

```
def walkAndList(self, directory):
# ...
def listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(self, aFileName):
```

Next, you are treating the `Toodles.isSourceFile()` and `Toodles.listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile()` methods as globals, you need to add `self.` in front of these to call them as methods on the current instance:

```
if(isSourceFile(filename)):
    listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(filename)
```

should be (without the redundant parenthesis):

```
if self.isSourceFile(filename):
    self.listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(filename)
```

You then refer to `filename` (which is missing the path) where you wanted `workingFilename` instead (which includes the path):

```
self.listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(workingFilename)
```

or you'll get errors opening those files.

Then, your file extension testing is flawed; just use `.endswith()` to prevent matching files such as `.csh` or `.h`. Moreover, there is no need to first ask `if` to test if something is `True`, then separately return `True` or `False`; you can return the boolean test *directly*:

```
def isSourceFile(self, name):
    return name.endswith(('.m', '.c', '.h'))
```

When counting along when looping over sequences, use the `enumerate()` function to generate the counter for you:

```
for currentLine, line in enumerate(input, 1):
    line = line.lower()
```

counts lines, starting from 1.

Note that `os.walk()` **already** traverses subdirectories for you. There is no need to recurse **again**. Remove the recursion by removing the lines:

```
for dirs in dirnames:
    self.walkAndList(os.path.join(dirname, dirs))
```

With a few more improvements (use `with` to have the open file closed again, set `needle` **outside** the loop, filter early, use string formatting, write out the original line, not lowercased), the full script becomes:

```
import os
import sys


class Toodles(object):
    def walkAndList(self, directory):
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                if self.isSourceFile(filename):
                    workingFilename = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                    self.listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(workingFilename)

            # Advanced usage:
            # editing the 'dirnames' list will stop os.walk() from recursing into there.
            if '.git' in dirnames:
                # don't go into any .git directories.
                dirnames.remove('.git')

    #   Find occurences of "todo" and "fixme" in a file
    #   If we find such an occurence, print the filename,
    #   the line number, and the line itself.
    def listOccurrencesOfToDoInFile(self, aFileName):
        needle = "todo"
        with open(aFileName) as input:
            for currentLine, line in enumerate(input, 1):
                if needle in line.lower():
                    sys.stdout.write('{}: ({}){}'.format(aFileName, currentLine, line))

    #Todo: add a comment
    def isSourceFile(self, name):
        return name.endswith(('.m', '.c', '.h'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Toodles()
    a.walkAndList('.')
```